# Как присоединять записи из таблиц по сложному условию

Tags: postgresql

Допустим есть таблица с некоторыми процессами, которые в ходе выполнения могут получать различные статусы:

```
 process               process_status
╔════╦════════╗       ╔════╦════════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ name   ║       ║ id ║ process_id ║ date       ║ status  ║
╠════╬════════╣       ╠════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║ 1  ║  One   ║       ║ 1  ║ 1          ║ 2018-10-10 ║ Start   ║ 
║ 2  ║  Two   ║       ║ 2  ║ 1          ║ 2018-10-15 ║ Running ║
║ 3  ║  Three ║       ║ 3  ║ 1          ║ 2018-10-30 ║ Running ║
╚════╩════════╝       ║ 4  ║ 1          ║ 2018-11-01 ║ Running ║
                      ║ 5  ║ 1          ║ 2018-11-02 ║ Error   ║
                      ║ 6  ║ 1          ║ 2018-11-03 ║ Error   ║
                      ╚════╩════════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

Как видно, статусы могут быть различные, а так-же каждый статус может быть получен несколько раз.

Меня интересуют только статусы `Running` и `Error`. Сейчас я получаю записи таким образом:

```
select p.id, p.name from process p 
  join process_status ps
  on p.id = ps.process_id
  where ps.status = 'Running' or ps.status = 'Error';
```

В итоге возвращается 5 строк. Три со статусом`Running` и две со статусом `Error`.

Можно ли как-то возвращать только 2 строки? Самый первый полученный `Running`(Если таковой вообще имеется) и/или самый первый полученный `Error`(Если таковой тоже имеется)?

В идеале вернуть все процессы у которых самый первый `Running` получен не позднее некоторой даты, например `2018-10-16` **ИЛИ** самый первый `Error` получен не позднее какой-то другой даты, например `2018-10-17`?

Возможно ли такое?

В итоге, в идеале, мне нужны только процессы удовлетворяющие этому условию:

```
╔══════╦════════╗ 
║ p.id ║ p.name ║   
╠══════╬════════╣
║ 1    ║  One   ║ 
╚══════╩════════╝
```

---

**UPD**
Немного поясню свою задачу:

Сейчас в системе из БД выгребаются все процессы и все их статусы `Running` и `Error`(примерно таким запросом, который я привел), и уже со стороны кода ищутся те процессы, которые получили первый статус `Running` или `Error` не позднее некоторой даты.

Дело в том. что ежедневно запускается порядка 8-10 тысяч(иногда больше) процессов, их число уже исчисляется десятками миллионов. Каждый процесс также получает порядка 10 тысяч статусов.

Прямо сейчас проблемы с производительностью нет, но я выполняю задачу, которая затрагивает этот код. На мой взгляд, из БД в приложение едет слишком много лишних данных. Поэтому раз уж все равно рефакторю этот участок кода, то хочу сделать оптимальнее, а именно не вычитывать миллионы процессов и выбирать из них в коде несколько десятков нужных, а возвращать сразу только те 10 нужных, и работать только с ними.

Comment: *Можно ли как-то возвращать только 2 строки?* Да. *В идеале вернуть все процессы* Но сначала подумайте - а нужны ли на самом деле все поля? наверное нет - и это очень упростит запрос. А если всё-же нужны - используйте FIRST_VALUE(). Или LATERAL JOIN к подзапросу, который получит даты таких записей.

Comment: @Akina Нужны в принципе только все поля первой таблицы

Comment: Ну так покажите требуемый результат на показанных модельных данных, и без излишков...

Comment: @Akina Не очень понял. В последнем абзаце как раз и описан желаемый результат.

Comment: Не-не-не. Вот точно так же, как исходник, покажите и результат. Поля и значения. И непременно сформулируйте ОДНО условие (пусть даже и сложное, составное), которому такой результат соответствует, без всякоразных жирных ИЛИ.

Comment: @Akina Я не могу убрать `ИЛИ`. Это условие бизнес процесса. Без этого `или` я и сам мог бы написать запрос, просто добавив `and ps.date::date < '2018-10-16'`. Но проблема как раз в том, что даты для разных статусов разные, и нужны все процессы, удовлетворяющие хотя бы одному из этих `или`.

Comment: @Akina Вообще этих `или` на самом деле много. Я в вопросе сократил до одного `или` для простоты. Мне достаточно понять как разобраться с одним, и тогда я смогу сам довести ответ из этого вопроса до того что мне нужно. Также добавил описание решаемой задачи в вопрос, может так понятнее будет, что мне нужно.

Comment: То есть это одно условие. Ок. Теперь ждём эталонный ответ для этого условия и этих исходных данных.

Comment: @Akina Добавил. Но все поля первой таблицы. это собственно просто первая таблица. Запрос тоже обновил маленько, убрал звездочку.

Comment: A как в результат попала запись p.id=2, если для неё вообще нет ни одной записи в process_status?

Comment: @Akina Вы правы, не доглядел в спешке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> вернуть все процессы у которых самый первый Running получен не позднее некоторой даты, например 2018-10-16 ИЛИ самый первый Error получен не позднее какой-то другой даты, например 2018-10-16

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM process t1, process_status t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.process_id 
  AND t2.date < '2018-10-16'
  AND t2.status IN ('Running', 'Error')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=147f4c628b16f8a6ffb2d97aab233930)

Если "не позднее какой-то другой даты" - это реально ДРУГОЙ, а в тексте одна и та же дата по ошибке, то

```
WHERE t1.id = t2.process_id 
  AND ( (t2.date < '2018-10-15' AND t2.status = 'Running' ) 
        OR
        (t2.date < '2018-10-16' AND t2.status = 'Error') )
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это, что мне нужно. В вопросе правда ошибка. У меня телефонное совещание, параллельно пишу код, параллельно сюда, поэтому допускаю ошибки от невнимательности.